I do an experiment which is a mixture of coin flip and uniform draw. Can I model this problem by conditional expectation as follows?
I want to model the following scenario. Suppose I flip a fair coin and if it is 'H'(Head), I draw a number uniformly from the set of real numbers $[0,M]$. So the expected value of the number I draw is $M/2$. If I flip 'T' (Tail), I draw from $[0,M/2]$. So the expected value of the number I draw is $M/4$.
I am having a hard time formalizing this setting. I am confused because I have two random variable which seem to live in two sample spaces. If I want to use conditional expectation, they need to be in the same probability space. And I don't know how to use the product space in this case. Any help, advice or insight would be greatly appreciated. My attempt is as follows.
Let $Z$ be the discrete random variable $Z:\{H,T\}\rightarrow \{1,1/2\}$ such that $Pr(Z=1)=Pr(Z=1/2)=1/2$. $X$ is a continuous random variable with the uniform distribution on $[0,MZ]$.
$\mathbb{E}[X/Z]=MZ/2$. Is this correct?
Edit: After reading heropup's answer, I have updated my notations as follows. Is that correct?
$Z=1 (\omega=H), Z=\frac{1}{2} (\omega =T)$.
$Z\sim{}Bernoulli(p=1/2)$.
$X\sim Uniform[0,MZ]$.
$\mathbb{E}(X/Z)=\frac{MZ}{2}$.

Had the second variable been the roll of a die, where if the first variable (the coin) has an outcome of heads, then you randomly roll/select among the outcomes $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, and if the coin is tails, then you randomly select among the outcomes $\{1, 2, 3\}$, then this should not present any difficulty with respect to enumerating the sample space of joint elementary outcomes:
$$\Omega = \{(H,1), (H,2), (H,3), (H,4), (H,5), (H,6), (T,1), (T,2), (T,3)\}.$$
Notice that this particular choice of sample space does not ensure each elementary outcome is equally likely.  This is because it does not capture the fact that heads and tails are equiprobable, in as much as if we constructed the sample space of a single toss of a biased coin, we might simply write $\{H, T\}$, but because the coin is biased, these outcomes are not equiprobable.  This is why we also define a probability function on the events in a sample space to obtain a probability space, which fully captures the behavior of the experiment.
It is natural to extend the above discrete example to the case where the second variable is uniformly distributed on the real interval $[0, M]$ when the coin is heads, and on $[0, M/2]$ when the coin is tails.  In such a case, $\Omega$ comprises the set of all ordered pairs of the form $(H,y_1)$ where $y_1 \in [0,M]$ and $(T,y_2)$ where $y_2 \in [0, M/2]$.
The difference between viewing the outcomes of this experiment as a pair of random variables, say $(X,Y)$, or as a single vector-valued random variable, is largely conceptual and not material to your computation.  Either way is fine.
If you were to ask me how I would characterize this experiment in terms of random variables, I would write
$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1, & \omega = H, \\ 0, & \omega = T, \end{cases}  \\  X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 1/2), \\
Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0, \tfrac{X+1}{2} M).$$
Notice that the second random variable is presented conditionally on $X$.  The marginal distribution of $Y$ is not uniform.

Thank you for your answer. Your answer is helpful in setting up the sample space from product. So in your approach $X=1$ for H, $X=0$ for T. In mine $Z=1$ for H and $Z=1/2$ for T. But the idea is the same, correct? In your case $\mathbb{E}(Y/X)=\frac{X+1}{4}M$. I will update my attempt in the question with your suggestion for product space. Would you kindly look over?

Your distributions is probably best understood as a mixture distribution.
A notable property of mixture distributions is that any expectation is a mixture of expectations, so e.g. for your case the mean will be:
$$
E(X) = P(H) E(X | H) + P(T) E(X | T) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{M}{2} + \frac{M}{4}\right) = \frac{3}{8}M
$$
